# How can I programmatically pin a textfield to the top of a view?

Tags: objective-c

I have added a textfield programmatically and it pins to the bottom of the view.

How can I pin it to the top of the view (or more exactly, pin it a few pixels below the top of the view)?

Comment: are you using Auto Layout? What have you tried/researched?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is assuming that you already have a pointer for this view (I am unsure if you have set it up in storyboard and haven't created an IBOutlet reference property) then this is the code to place your textView at the top of your view (I have named the reference to your view YOUR_VIEW - replace this with the pointer to your view):

```
UITextView *txtView = [[UITextView alloc]
initWithFrame:CGRectMake(YOUR_VIEW.frame.origin.x , YOUR_VIEW.frame.origin.y, 250, 50)];
[YOUR_VIEW addsubview:txtView];
```

The most important thing to take away from this CGRectMake("x position", "y position", "width", "height") which is the method used to define a views size and position. Reference to this can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html).

I hope this is what you are looking for. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

There's many ways to do this. It can really depend on how many assets you have in the view, if the textfield is relying on other views, autolayout etc. Something like this could work.

```
self.textField.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y, self.textField.frame.size.width, self.textField.frame.size.height);
```